# opencv Mat datatype conversion and arithmetic

Tags: c++, opencv, types

I am new to the opencv library and still confused about the C++ Mat class since 2.x.

The problems I faced:

1. non-template version of class Mat is runtime typed, but there are no functions that can show the symbolic name of a Mat object, there is only a `cv::Mat::type()`, which returns integer.
2. If a matrix is of CV_8U, or unsigned char type, then I do addition arithmetic...does it has the possibility of causing overflow? or opencv is smart enough to convert datatype and do so called "saturated arithmetic"? e.g.

   `unsigned char a = 255; unsigned char b = a+a; // == 255`

   operations of a+a:

   `unsigned char b = (unsigned char) clipTo_0_255((float)a + (float)a));`
3. If I want to avoid subtle `cv::Mat::at<_Tp>`, most solutions suggest using derived template version of `class Mat_<_Tp>`. But _Tp must C++ primitive type and I don't know the mapping between primitive type and CvMat type system... (Maybe it is straightforward...)
4. Is opencv datatype conversion equivalent to C/C++ type casting? e.g.

   `float a = 1.5; int b = (int) a; // == 1`

   `int a = 2; float b = static_cast<int>(a); // == 2.0`

Comment: By the way...experiments showed many opencv functions will return Mat with CV_8U type...

Answer (score 1):

For both #2 and #4, you should read the [OpenCV page on saturation arithmetic](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#saturation-arithmetics). In particular:

> This “saturation” semantics (different
>   from usual C language “wrapping”
>   semantics, where lowest bits are
>   taken, is implemented in every image
>   processing function, from the simple
>   `cv::add` to `cv::cvtColor`, `cv::resize`,
>   `cv::filter2D` etc. It is not a new
>   feature of OpenCV v2.x, it was there
>   from very beginning. In the new
>   version this special template operator
>   is introduced to simplify
>   implementation of this semantic in
>   your own functions.

I unfortunately do not have any great solutions to your issues with the type system. Because all of the OpenCV library functions use the non-templated `cv::Mat` class, I personally have given up on using `cv::Mat<T>` class until the rest of the API is updated.

While the type system is fairly awkward, it becomes much easier to use as you grow accustom to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer~ I will try to get accustomed to it

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. I'd love to hear if you find a solution to #3: it is perpetually irritating when writing OpenCV code that must work on multiple data types. I believe this is internally done with a `switch` statement, so my hopes are not high...

Comment: 3 years later, we're at the same stage. I think OpenCV's `Mat` is here to stay...